# Tabulator isn't adjusting the height of the column header if the header is nested

Tags: tabulator

tabulator version: 4.8

I've tried it for hours, but I am stuck.

The height of the column header isn't auto-adjusted in the header second line. So important text for a column is hidden.

So, if you have a very long header title like "Anzahl Böden" or "Tragkraft pro Boden" you only see the first word if your screen size is not big enough.

```js
    
/* tabulator */
var locale_number_formatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
    return nf.format( cell.getValue() );
}

function is_mobile() {
    var is_mobile = true;
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        is_mobile = false;
    }
    return is_mobile;
}
```

```css
.is-hidden
{
  display: none;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-col-content .tabulator-col-title {
    white-space: normal !important;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.8.4/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.8.4/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1>
      Table test
    </h1>

    <div id="product-table-2371">

    </div>
    <div id="hidden-table-2371">

    </div>

<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

          var cart_formatter_2371 = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
            return '<button title="In den Warenkorb" class="button cart-table-button cart-table-button-2371 is-primary has-text-white is-size-7 modal-button" data-object-id="238" data-attribute-id="2371" data-variation-id="' + cell.getValue() + '" aria-haspopup="true" data-table-id="table_2371">Warenkorb</button>';
          };

          var responsive_layout_formatter_2371 = function(data) {
            //data - an array of objects containing the column title and value for each cell
            var table_data = [];

            data.forEach(function(col) {
              table_data.push({
                'column': col.title,
                celldata: col.value
              });
            });

            var responsive_table_2371 = Tabulator.prototype.findTable("#hidden-table-2371")[0];

            if (!responsive_table_2371) {
              responsive_table_2371 = new Tabulator("#hidden-table-2371", {
                tooltips: true,
                autoColumns: true,
                "headerVisible": false,
                layout: 'fitColumns',
                tooltipGenerationMode: "hover",
                tooltipsHeader: true,
                data: table_data
              });
            } else {
              responsive_table_2371.clearData();
              responsive_table_2371.clearFilter();
              responsive_table_2371.setData(table_data);
            }

            //var table_html = responsive_table_2371.tabulator( "getHtml" );
            var table_html = '';

            return Object.keys(data).length ? table_html : "";
          }

          var cart_button_cell_click_2371 = function(e, cell) {

            // dummy

          };


          var columns_json_2371 = [{
            "title": "",
            "tooltip": "",
            "cssClass": "tabulator-header-row-level-2",
            "columns": [{
              "formatter": "plaintext",
              "field": "no",
              "title": "Nr.",
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "width": 60,
              "resizable": false,
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "height",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-height",
              "title": "H\u00f6he",
              "tooltip": "H\u00f6he in mm",
              "sorter": "number",
              "formatter": locale_number_formatter,
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "length",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-length",
              "title": "L\u00e4nge",
              "tooltip": "L\u00e4nge in mm",
              "sorter": "number",
              "formatter": locale_number_formatter,
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "depth",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-depth",
              "title": "Tiefe",
              "tooltip": "Tiefe in mm",
              "sorter": "number",
              "formatter": locale_number_formatter,
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "lowershelf",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-lowershelf",
              "title": "Anzahl B\u00f6den",
              "tooltip": "Anzahl der Fachb\u00f6den pro Regalfeld",
              "sorter": "number",
              "formatter": locale_number_formatter,
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "tragkraft_pro_boden",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-tragkraft_pro_boden",
              "title": "Tragkraft pro Boden",
              "tooltip": "Tragkraft pro Boden in kg",
              "sorter": "string",
              "formatter": "plaintext",
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }]
          }, {
            "title": "Grundregal",
            "tooltip": "Hier steht das Grundregal",
            "cssClass": "tabulator-header-row-level-2",
            "columns": [{
              "field": "sku",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-sku",
              "title": "Art.Nr.",
              "tooltip": "Artikelnummer des Produkts",
              "sorter": "alphanum",
              "formatter": "plaintext",
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "price",
              "cssClass": "tabulator-col-price",
              "title": "Preis",
              "tooltip": "Produktpreis",
              "sorter": "number",
              "formatter": "money",
              "titleFormatter": "textarea",
              "variableHeight": true,
              "formatterParams": {
                "decimal": ",",
                "thousand": ".",
                "symbol": " \u20ac",
                "symbolAfter": true,
                "precision": "2"
              },
              "hozAlign": "right",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "cart",
              "formatter": cart_formatter_2371,
              "cellClick": cart_button_cell_click_2371,
              "hozAlign": "center",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "tooltip": "In den Warenkorb",
              "title": "",
              "cssClass": "tabulatur-background-price",
              "headerSort": false,
              "responsive": 2
            }]
          }, {
            "title": "Anbauregal",
            "tooltip": "Hier ist das Anbauregal",
            "cssClass": "tabulator-header-row-level-2",
            "columns": [{
              "field": "sku_1",
              "formatter": "plaintext",
              "hozAlign": "center",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "sorter": "alphanum",
              "title": "Art.Nr.",
              "tooltip": "Artikelnummer des Produkts",
              "cssClass": "tabulatur-background-anbauregal",
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "price_1",
              "formatter": "money",
              "hozAlign": "center",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "sorter": "number",
              "title": "Preis",
              "cssClass": "tabulatur-background-anbauregal",
              "formatterParams": {
                "decimal": ",",
                "thousand": ".",
                "symbol": " \u20ac",
                "symbolAfter": true,
                "precision": "2"
              },
              "responsive": 2
            }, {
              "field": "cart_1",
              "formatter": cart_formatter_2371,
              "cellClick": cart_button_cell_click_2371,
              "hozAlign": "center",
              "vertAlign": "middle",
              "tooltip": "In den Warenkorb",
              "title": "",
              "cssClass": "tabulatur-background-anbauregal",
              "headerSort": false,
              "responsive": 2
            }]
          }];

          var tabledata_2371 = [{
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "300",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2626",
            "price": "145",
            "cart": "307831",
            "sku_1": "S2646",
            "price_1": "108.1",
            "cart_1": "307847",
            "no": 1
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "400",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2627",
            "price": "154.7",
            "cart": "307832",
            "sku_1": "S2647",
            "price_1": "117.1",
            "cart_1": "307848",
            "no": 2
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "500",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2628",
            "price": "173.2",
            "cart": "307833",
            "sku_1": "S2648",
            "price_1": "134.6",
            "cart_1": "307849",
            "no": 3
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "600",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2629",
            "price": "189.2",
            "cart": "307834",
            "sku_1": "S2649",
            "price_1": "149.6",
            "cart_1": "307850",
            "no": 4
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "800",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2630",
            "price": "213.5",
            "cart": "307835",
            "sku_1": "S2650",
            "price_1": "171.7",
            "cart_1": "307851",
            "no": 5
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "300",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2633",
            "price": "178.3",
            "cart": "307836",
            "sku_1": "S2653",
            "price_1": "140.5",
            "cart_1": "307852",
            "no": 6
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "400",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2634",
            "price": "194.3",
            "cart": "307837",
            "sku_1": "S2654",
            "price_1": "155.8",
            "cart_1": "307853",
            "no": 7
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "500",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2635",
            "price": "218.9",
            "cart": "307838",
            "sku_1": "S2655",
            "price_1": "179.3",
            "cart_1": "307854",
            "no": 8
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "600",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2636",
            "price": "236",
            "cart": "307839",
            "sku_1": "S2656",
            "price_1": "195.5",
            "cart_1": "307855",
            "no": 9
          }, {
            "height": "2000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "800",
            "lowershelf": "5",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2637",
            "price": "300.3",
            "cart": "307840",
            "sku_1": "S2657",
            "price_1": "257.6",
            "cart_1": "307856",
            "no": 10
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "500",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2715",
            "price": "322",
            "cart": "307898",
            "sku_1": "S2735",
            "price_1": "258.9",
            "cart_1": "307912",
            "no": 38
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "600",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2716",
            "price": "346.2",
            "cart": "307899",
            "sku_1": "S2736",
            "price_1": "281.6",
            "cart_1": "307913",
            "no": 39
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1300",
            "depth": "800",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "250 kg",
            "sku": "S2717",
            "price": "436.6",
            "cart": "307900",
            "sku_1": "S2737",
            "price_1": "368.7",
            "cart_1": "307914",
            "no": 40
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "300",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "330 kg",
            "sku": "S2961",
            "price": "239.6",
            "cart": "307901",
            "sku_1": "S2971",
            "price_1": "180.8",
            "cart_1": "307915",
            "no": 41
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "400",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "330 kg",
            "sku": "S2962",
            "price": "263.2",
            "cart": "307902",
            "sku_1": "S2972",
            "price_1": "203.5",
            "cart_1": "307916",
            "no": 42
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "500",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "330 kg",
            "sku": "S2963",
            "price": "291.5",
            "cart": "307903",
            "sku_1": "S2973",
            "price_1": "230.2",
            "cart_1": "307917",
            "no": 43
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "600",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "330 kg",
            "sku": "S2964",
            "price": "316.1",
            "cart": "307904",
            "sku_1": "S2974",
            "price_1": "253.2",
            "cart_1": "307918",
            "no": 44
          }, {
            "height": "3000",
            "length": "1000",
            "depth": "800",
            "lowershelf": "7",
            "tragkraft_pro_boden": "330 kg",
            "sku": "S2965",
            "price": "349.5",
            "cart": "307919",
            "sku_1": "S2975",
            "price_1": "283.5",
            "cart_1": "307920",
            "no": 45
          }];

          var table_layout_2371 = 'fitColumns';
          var paginationSize_2371 = 10;

          if (is_mobile()) {
            table_layout_2371 = 'fitData';
            paginationSize_2371 = 1;
          }
          var table_2371 = new Tabulator("#product-table-2371", {
            "data": tabledata_2371,
            "locale": "de-de",
            "columnHeaderVertAlign": "bottom",

            "langs": {
              "de-de": {
                "pagination": {
                  "page_size": "Einträge pro Seite",
                  "page_title": "Seite anzeigen",
                  "first": "Erste",
                  "first_title": "Erste Seite",
                  "last": "Letzte",
                  "last_title": "Letzte Seite",
                  "prev": "Zurück",
                  "prev_title": "Zurück",
                  "next": "Weiter",
                  "next_title": "Nächste Seite",
                  "all": "Alle"
                }
              }
            },

            "tooltips": true,
            "pagination": 'local',
            "paginationSize": paginationSize_2371,
            "paginationSizeSelector": true,
            "paginationSizeSelector": [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
            "responsiveLayout": "collapse",
            "layout": table_layout_2371,
            initialSort: [{
              "column": "height",
              "dir": "asc"
            }],
            "selectable": true,
            "tooltipGenerationMode": "hover",
            "tooltipsHeader": true,
            "responsiveLayoutCollapseFormatter": responsive_layout_formatter_2371,
            "columns": columns_json_2371
          });

          table_2371.clearData();
          table_2371.clearFilter();
          table_2371.setData(tabledata_2371);




          var table_filter_2371 = $(".product-filter-2371");

          if (table_filter_2371.length) {
            table_filter_2371.change(function() {
              table_2371.clearFilter();

              var filter_array_2371 = [];

              $(".product-filter-2371").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                  filter_array_2371.push({
                    'field': $(this).data('column'),
                    'type': '=',
                    'value': $(this).val()
                  });
                }
              });

              table_2371.setFilter(filter_array_2371);

            });
          }

        });

      </script>
```

Any ideas?

Best,
Georg.

Comment: could you post a link to a JS fiddle that shows your code in action? it is very hard to offer advice on large blocks of code :)

Comment: Hi Oli, I've included the code here in stack overflow (Run code snippet). But I've copied the code in fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/gfranz75/z8jL73df/11/